# Pass data from a CSVReader to a method inside a loop

Tags: c#, list, loops, csv

I have a CSV with the following data

```
month,year,speed
12,2010,76
2,2000,45
12,1940,30
```

and I'm loading using a 3rd party that reads it. In short, it is a CSVReader class and able to get the data from a file called *input* like this

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> data = CSVReader.Read("input");
```

Then, using a for loop I'm capable of retrieving the data this way

```
for(var i=0; i < data.Count; i++) {
    print ("month" + data[i]["month"] + " " +
           "year" + data[i]["year"] + " " +
           "speed " + data[i]["speed"]);
}
```

Except inside of the for loop I want to pass each year and month (one by one) to another function that takes as argument something like doubles (not objects) and i don't know how

```
for(var i=0; i < data.Count; i++) {
    // Get month and year
    function(month, year);
}
```

Comment: function(data[i].month, data[i].year);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly interpret this and your question is: "How do I pass a value of type `object` to a function that takes a parameter of type `double`?", then you could either:
1) Cast the value
like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++) {
    double month = (double)data[i]["month"];
    // Same for year.
    function(month, year);
}
```

Note that if the values you are casting cannot be casted to the target type (i.e., csv you are reading contains some corrupted rows), that would cause an exception to be thrown. If you're certain that won't be the problem, you can just do this, however, if you want to be sure, you can go with the option 2 which is
2) Use the `as` operator
like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++) {
    double? month = data[i]["month"] as double?;
    if (!month.HasValue) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Month value on line {i + 1} is corrupted; Skipping...");
        break;
    }
    // Same for year.
    function(month.Value, year.Value);
}
```

In this case if the value is not of the `double` type, the `month` will be assigned the value of `null` (that's why we use the nullable `double?` type). That allows you to check whether the conversion was successful without having to handle possible exceptions.

Comment: The CSV doesn't have the headers specified. How could I still add it without creating the headers in the file?

Comment: @BárbaraPeres If you are experiencing an additional problem, you should ask a separate question. Also consider adding more context, it is difficult to understand the problem from only two short sentences.

Comment: It is the same question, the difference is that the header isn't in the file (but i know what it is)

Comment: @BárbaraPeres I'm sorry, but I'm not completely sure I understand you. Are you saying that your CSV data doesn't have header row anymore, i.e. instead of: `month,year,speed \n 12,2010,76 \n ...` you now have: `12,2010,76 \n ...`?

Comment: Yes, I wrote the header just to show the numbers have meaning

Comment: @BárbaraPeres Well, in that case some of the information provided simply doesn't make any sense:
1) You say that you are of retrieving data like this: `data[i]["month"]`, yet there is no `month` field to begin with
2) I don't know the particular `CSVReader.Read()` method, but judging from your post, you managed to read your data into a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`. However, if there is no header information, your dictionary keys become either `null` or (less likely) an empty string. Both of these cases would lead to exception throwing when adding entries to your dictionary.

Comment: @BárbaraPeres So it appears that some relevant information is missing. I suggest you add that in separate question as this has nothing to do with the original (how to convert `object` to `double`).

Comment: I followed your advice - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58748243/how-to-read-a-csv-with-no-headers